# How to make Adaptivetheme dropdown menu show on start page?

Tags: navigation

I'm using Drupal 8 with an Adaptivetheme subtheme. The horizontal navigation menu resides in the leader board region. Some menu entries have submenus, but they do not show on the start page. One has to click on the respective menu (e.g. "Football"), which loads the single page "Football", and it is only here that submenus will be shown.

Is there a way to make submenus work on the start page with Adaptivetheme?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the relevant menu at /admin/structure/menu/

Edit each (first level) items that is not showing it's submenu items and tick off "show as expanded".

This is a general tip. I don't know exactly how your theme works.

Comment: That solved the issue. Instead of showing the whole menu tree expanded (as I assumed), it simply adds a dropdown arrow which expands the menu  on hovering. Thanks!

Comment: It is showing all the submenu items of the expanded menu item. Your theme is probably just hiding them until the parent item is hovered using css/javascript/jquery. If this solved your problem, you can also mark the answer accepted.